# how fix the background color of a page independent of the theme in wp7?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

I just want a particular page to be with white background color whatever may be the theme.
How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try setting the Background property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If background disappears,
then create an event handler for **TextBox_GotFocus**.

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var clickedUIElement = sender as TextBox;
        clickedUIElement.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

set Background of the layout root like this

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Black">
```

Comment: but in this case, when selecting a textbox the border of the textbox disappears.

Comment: well you would have to learn to make styles of the UI elements, The solution given downside works well for a textbox but, while making the application you would need other Ui elements as well(Like Radiobuttons, Buttons,Checkboxes etc). Styling would allow you to design the UI according to your choice no matter what the phones background color is.